# NiFi MergeRecords leaving out one file

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi to take in some user data and combine all the JSONs into one record. The MergeRecord processor is working just like I need, except it ***always*** leaves out one record (usually the same one every time). The processor is set to run ever 60 seconds. I can't understand why because there are only 56 records to merge. I've included images below for any help y'all may have.

[image: Records waiting for Processor to activate]

[image: One record leftover in queue]

[image: Processor Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have 56 **FlowFiles**, that does not necessarily mean 56 **Records** unless you have 1 Record per FlowFile.

You are using MergeRecord which counts Records, not files.

Your current config is set to Min 50 - Max 1000 **Records**

If you have 56 files with 1 Record in each, then merging 50 files is enough to meet the Minimum condition and release the bucket.

You also say Merge is set to run every 60 seconds, and perhaps this is not doing what you think it is. In almost all cases, Merge should be left to the default 0 sec schedule.

NiFi has no idea what *all* means, it takes an input and works on it - it does not know if or when the next input will come.

If every FlowFile is 1 Record, and it is categorically always 56 and that will never change, then your setting could be Min 56 - Max 56 and that will always merge 56 times.

However, that is very inflexible to change - if it suddenly changed to 57, you need to modify the flow.

Instead, you could set the Min-Max to very high numbers, say 10,000-20,000 and then set a Max Bin Age to 60 seconds (and the processor scheduling back to 0 sec). This would have the effect of merging every Record that enters the processor until A) 10-20k Records have been merged, or B) 60 seconds expire.

Example scenarios:

A) All 56 arrives within the first 2 seconds of the flow starting

- All 56 are merged into 1 file after 60 seconds of the first file arriving

B) 53 arrive within the first 60 seconds, 3 arrive in the second 60 seconds

- The first 53 are merged into 1 file after 60 seconds of the first file arriving, the last 3 are merged into another file after 60 seconds from the frst of the 3 arriving

C) 10,000 arrive in the first 5 seconds

- All 10k will merge immediately into 1 file, they will not wait for 60 seconds